# How to use decimal number without creating a String resource

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In Java and Kotlin there is an API that can used to show a time without having to create a string resource.

In the example line of code below, this value allows the time of 8 hours after midnight to automatically chnage the way its displayed depending on the device locale.

```
    val timeCustom = LocalTime.of(8, 0)
```

Is there something similar that can be used for a decimal number, where the value automatically uses a specific demical symbol dpending on the locale? (`.` or `,`).

For example, to describe the height of something (e.g. 5 point 2 metres):

```
    val decimalNumber = Decimal.of(5,2)
```

Is there something like this available?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Locale.getDefault()` e.g.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();

        Integer quantity = 123456;
        Double amount = 345987.246;
        NumberFormat numberFormatter;
        String quantityOut;
        String amountOut;

        numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(currentLocale);
        quantityOut = numberFormatter.format(quantity);
        amountOut = numberFormatter.format(amount);
        System.out.println(quantityOut);
        System.out.println(amountOut);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123,456
345,987.246
```